# Using MartenDB for Eventsourcing with Azure Postgres database

Tags: c#, postgresql, azure, marten

We're trying to configure `Marten` as our EventStore using a `Postgres` database in `Azure`. We've provisioned a `Azure Database for PostgreSQL single server` in Azure.

Ideally we would like `Marten` to create the database if it not exists. Our problem is that `CreateDatabasesForTenants` never gets called during `services.AddMarten`. This is our code:

```
services.AddMarten(options =>
{
    var connection =
        @"Server=databaseServerName.postgres.database.azure.com;Database=myDatabase;Port=5432;User Id=admin@databaseServerName;Password=apassword;Ssl Mode=VerifyCA;";

    var maintenanceconnectionString = @"Server=databaseServerName.postgres.database.azure.com;Database=postgres;Port=5432;User Id=admin@databaseServerName;Password=apassword;Ssl Mode=VerifyCA;";
    
    options.Connection(connection);
    options.CreateDatabasesForTenants(options =>
    {
        options.MaintenanceDatabase(maintenanceconnectionString);
        
        options.ForTenant()
            .CheckAgainstPgDatabase()
            .WithOwner("postgres")
            .WithEncoding("UTF-8")
            .ConnectionLimit(-1)
            .OnDatabaseCreated(_ =>
            {
              
            });
    });
});
```

Everytime we access the `IDocumentStore` we get the following message:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 3D000: database "myDatabase" does not exist
```

Obviously, it doesn't exist, but why is the `CreateDatabaseForTenants` never called? What am I missing here?

Comment: It appears that the CreateDatabasesForTenants function is not being used because no code path in your application appears to be triggering its execution. You must specifically call the EnsureStorageExists function on the IDocumentStore interface in Marten in order to build a new database.

Comment: Cheers @Sourav. I’ll try that asap.

Comment: There are no `EnsureStorageExists` function on `IDocumentStore` as far as I can tell. https://github.com/JasperFx/marten/blob/master/src/Marten/IDocumentStore.cs